# C++ string split and manipulation

Tags: c++, string, split

The strings are all this way:

```
 string s="name_number";
```

I'd like to separate the name from the number and get two string "name" and "number". Then I need the number to do an addition:

```
int new_number=number+10;
```

and rebuild the string with "name_newnumber".
is there a smart and fast way to do that? It's program with real time constraints so it should be as fast as possible. I only came up with split or find_first_of but I was wondering if there is something better

Comment: Presumably `number` is comprised of numerals, not spelt out?

Comment: He got a String "name_10" and needs to change it to "name_11", "name_12" and so on. Get the position of the underscore and convert position + 1 of the underscore to an int, add your value and create a new string.

Comment: Shouldn't be too bad to make it faster. Take the last character, increment it, accounting for `'9'` -> `'0'` and move left if that happens. Repeat, or insert a `'1'` if no digit is there.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done before asking for help?

Comment: I know this sounds stale, but: Did you profile your program and find proof that the naive "find_first_of" approach is too slow?

Comment: It was just looking for perfection, even ms can make the difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following as an idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s = "name_5";

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    std::string::size_type n = s.rfind( '_' );

    if ( n != std::string::npos )
    {
        s.replace( n + 1, std::string::npos, 
                   std::to_string( std::stoi( s.substr( n + 1 ) ) + 10 ) );
    }

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
name_5
name_15
```

Take into account that I used method `rfind` instead of `find`. In this case the name may contain an embedded underscore.

For example if you will initialize the string as

```
std::string s="Main_Name_  5";
```

you will get

```
Main_Name_  5
Main_Name_15
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily extract everything with a `std::istringstream`:

```
std::istringstream iss(s);

std::string name;
std::getline(iss, name, '_');
int number;
iss >> number;
```

Then do whatever you want with `number` to get `newnumber`, and then concatenate it all together again:

```
std::string newstring = name + "_" + std::to_string(newnumber);
```

This could easily do with some more error checking though (for example, if the stream extraction fails).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick

```
 std::string abc = "name_10";
 std::string name = abc.substr(0, abc.find('_'));
 int i = std::stoi(abc.substr(abc.find('_') + 1));
 // change i
 ++i;
 abc = name + '_' + std::to_string(i);
```